# SQL getting opposite results due to mistaking 1 and 0, vise-versa

Tags: php, mysql, search, boolean

In this piece of code, I am trying to test out this boolean method of checking data. What this project is for is to make a Food Budgeting System for our school campus. In this rudimentary stage, I have set-up a table which has a boolean to detect different options.

```
<?php

$db_host = "db4free.net";
$db_name = "testable";
$db_username = "muymuy1";
$db_password = "Muymuy2002";

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host; dbname=$db_name; charset=utf8", "$db_username", "$db_password") or die("error");

$sql = "INSERT INTO `food` (name, id, price, isForSingle, isForPair, isForSharing, isFullMeal) VALUES ('Sanwhich 234', NULL, 110, 1, 0, 0, 0)";
$db->query($sql) or die("Something happened");

$sql = "DELETE FROM `food` WHERE name LIKE '%sanwhich%'";
$stmt = $db->query($sql) or die("error 4");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `food` WHERE isForSingle=0";
$stmt = $db->query($sql) or die("error 5");

$data = array();
$count = 0;

if($stmt !== false)
{
     while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        { 
            $data[$count] = array(
                "id" => $row['id'],
                "name" => $row['name'],
                "price" => $row['price'],
                "isFullMeal" => $row['isFullMeal'],
                "isForSharing" => $row['isForSharing'],
                "isForPair" => $row['isForPair'],
                "isForSingle" => $row['isForSingle'],
             );
         $count += 1;
      }

 }

echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';


?>
```

### Table Data:

[image: MySQL Table]

However, my problem is that this is not working. The one 0 is confused with 1 and 1 with 0, as when I search with the `WHERE isForPair = 0`, what appears is the data rows which have 1, while when I search `WHERE isForPair = 1`, what appears is the data rows which have 0.

### 1) ... WHERE isForPair = 0 (Output: Results that isForPair = 1)

[image: Example 1]

### 2) ... WHERE isForPair = 1 (Output: None, though all in the table are isForPair = 1)

[image: Example 2]

Comment: Please add the `CREATE TABLE...` statements to your question

Comment: BTW: You should ensure case-sensitivy in your `DELETE` : `DELETE FROM food WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%sanwhich%'`

Comment: Oh thanks for the advice :) However, these CREATE TABLE thing was done statically, like with PHPmyadmin.co, thus I didn't add any CREATE TABLE statements and second, the delete thing doesn't really play much of a role in my code, it was for testing a DELETE, rather than my problem right now [Not trying to be rude, honestly :)]

Comment: He meant the output of `show create table xxx`. It doesn't matter in which way it was created. What happens if you enter your select-query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: I am sorry for my ignorance, but I don't gets

Comment: Enter the following code in phpmyadmin, mysql or any other tool of your choice: `show create table food;`. Add the result to your question. Then do the same for `SELECT * FROM food WHERE id = 1` and for `SELECT * FROM food WHERE id = 1 and isForPair=0;` and for `SELECT * FROM food WHERE id = 1 and isForPair=1;`

Answer (score 0):

The DDL statement of your table (`CREATE TABLE`) statement must match with the query. It seems that you want to match the data in your tables with a boolean. In this case, you can make the field `isForSingle` into `TINYINT` data type in your database.

**Note:** `BOOLEAN` and `TINYINT` are the same [in MySQL RDBMS.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Here is the DDL statement I have tried.

```
CREATE TABLE food (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(100), isForSingle TINYINT);
```

Then, I insert 2 records.

```
INSERT INTO food VALUES(1,'Hamburger',1);
INSERT INTO food VALUES(2,'Pizza',0);
```

Then, I try to query the data with your PHP code.

```
<?php

$db_host = "YOURDBHOST";
$db_name = "YOURDATABASE";
$db_username = "YOURUSERNAME";
$db_password = "YOURPASSWORD";

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host; dbname=$db_name; charset=utf8", "$db_username", "$db_password") or die("error");

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `food` WHERE isForSingle=1";
$stmt = $db->query($sql) or die("error");

$data = array();
$count = 0;

if($stmt !== false)
{
     while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        { 
            $data[$count] = array(
                "id" => $row['id'],
                "name" => $row['name'],
                "isForSingle" => $row['isForSingle'],
             );
         $count += 1;
      }

 }

var_dump($data);
// -----------------------------------------------------------------



// ------------------------------------------------------------------
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `food` WHERE isForSingle=0";
$stmt = $db->query($sql) or die("error");

$data = array();
$count = 0;

if($stmt !== false)
{
     while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        { 
            $data[$count] = array(
                "id" => $row['id'],
                "name" => $row['name'],
                "isForSingle" => $row['isForSingle'],
             );
         $count += 1;
      }

 }

var_dump($data);
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the result is below.

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    'id' =>
    string(1) "1"
    'name' =>
    string(9) "Hamburger"
    'isForSingle' =>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    'id' =>
    string(1) "2"
    'name' =>
    string(5) "Pizza"
    'isForSingle' =>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.